# Can´t install Pytorch on PyCharm: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0+cpu

Tags: pycharm, pytorch

I tried multiple times installing Pytorch on Pycharm. I used the code that the pytorch web site give you for a specific configuration. I use this one:

[image]

Then I copied this information on Pycharm Terminal and I get this message:

(venv) D:\Usuarios\AuCap\Documents\mnist>pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/w
hl/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0+cpu

I also tried installing it using Python interpreter in the Pycharm Settings and also didnd´t work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: hey men did u solve it?, im having the same issue

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade your Python version as `python3.9` is not supported by PyTorch right now (`python3.8` is fine though).
See [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/45731), it will be supported in subsequent releases.

You can build your own PyTorch from source if you wish though.

Comment: In the downgrade process, I uninstalled the `Python 3.9` and install `Python 3.8.2`. As the output of `python --version` says, now I have python `3.8.2` but I still get the same error when trying to install torch. Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Try using "Repair" option in Python Setup Window (Windows options -> Apps -> Find Python -> Modify -> Repair).

I had exactly the same problem and it worked for me.

PS: also make sure you have Python 64-bit version

Answer (score 1):

This now works with Python 3.9 (64 bit) and PyTorch 1.9. Using the website widget I was able to install on Windows using:

`pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio===0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

The answer by @Szymon Maszke above was correct at the time it was posted, but the [underlying issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/45731) has since been patched.