# ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch===1.7.0+cu110

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Hi I got an error while trying to install pytorch:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> pip install torch===1.7.0+cu110 torchvision===0.8.1+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.7.0+cu110 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch===1.7.0+cu110
```

[image]

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636103/can%c2%b4t-install-pytorch-on-pycharm-no-matching-distribution-found-for-torch-1-7), and I am using python 3.8.6

```
PS C:\windows\system32> py --version
Python 3.8.6
```

Comment: Try python 3.7.

Comment: @B200011011, Hi Sorry my bad, I installed 32 bits python instead of 64 bits, now it works.

Answer (score -1):

The newest version of torch is 1.7.0, so

```sh
pip install torch
```

should be enough.

Comment: Hi, does this comes with cuda support?

Comment: I don't know anything about that library. Please consult their [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/torch/).